# Defining class type in type typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using ts in one of my project and I am kinda of  beginner here:

I have something like this

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { Request } from "express";

export interface FileStorage {
  storage: admin.storage.Storage;
  rootBucket: any,
  bucketName: string | undefined;
}

export class FileStorage implements FileStorage {
  constructor() {
    this.storage = admin.storage();
    this.rootBucket = this.storage.bucket();
    this.bucketName = admin.instanceId().app.options.storageBucket;
  }
```

In the above code snippet, the type of my rootBucket is `any`. I want it to be more precise:

This is the interface of storage

```
  interface Storage {
    /**
     * Optional app whose `Storage` service to
     * return. If not provided, the default `Storage` service will be returned.
     */
    app: admin.app.App;
    /**
     * @returns A [Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/Bucket)
     * instance as defined in the `@google-cloud/storage` package.
     */
    bucket(name?: string): Bucket;
  }
}
```

and If I `cmd + click` on Bucket then it takes it u

```
declare class Bucket extends ServiceObject {
```

You can find declare class Bucket [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/7da03797791ed20ffbbc6456c7cfad1653c59e76/src/bucket.ts#L393) on github

Comment: *"I want it to be more precise"* If you mean the type of `rootBucket`, I don't see how we can tell you that. We don't know your project or what you're doing. On the face of it, the type woudl be `Bucket`, but...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't want it to be `any`. For example I was able to figure out the type of storage by looking into index.d.ts i.e ` storage: admin.storage.Storage;` but I am unable to figure out the type for `rootBucket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can skip the interface and declare the member variables in the class directly.
You can import the Bucket class from the library and use it your class:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { Bucket } from "@google-cloud/storage"

export class FileStorage {
  storage: admin.storage.Storage = admin.storage();
  rootBucket: Bucket;
  bucketName: string | undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.rootBucket = this.storage.bucket();
    this.bucketName = admin.instanceId().app.options.storageBucket;
  }
```